# How to use data provided by Ajax in flask?

Tags: python, flask, youtube-data-api

So I was starting out with Flask and thought of creating a Youtube search engine wherein I will be taking data from the user through Html from and send that data to Flask using Ajax.

Here is the code for my index html page:

```
{% extends "layout.html" %}
{% block content %}
<script type=text/javascript>
  $(function() {
    $("#echoText").keyup(function() {
         $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: $SCRIPT_ROOT + "/echo/",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            data: { echoValue: $('input[name="echoText"]').val() },
            success: function(data) {
                $('#echoResult').text(data.value);
            }
        });     
    });
  });
</script>
<strong>Enter a value to echo back:</strong>
<input type='text' size='10' id='echoText' name='echoText'>
<button type='button' id='submitBtn' name='submitBtn'>Submit via AJAX</button><br /><br />
<div id='echoResult'></div>



{% endblock %}
```

And here is my flask app python file:

```
from flask import Flask, jsonify, render_template, request

import youtube
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('index.html')

@app.route('/echo/', methods=['GET'])
def echo():
    ret_data = {"value":youtube.youtube_search(request.args.get('echoValue'))[1][0]["id"]["videoId"]}
    data = jsonify(ret_data)
    return data

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(port=5000, debug=True)
```

So right now I am able to transfer the data from Html page to flask but I some how want to use the data return a YouTube video embedded in my Html page. How can I do that?

Comment: Looks like you want to embed a video into your HTML. More of an HTML question. You may check [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/video)

Comment: Ywah I want to embed the video. but i can only return the data and not use it anywhere else.